# Inconveniente al relacionar dos tablas en el Mysql (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Deseo solicitarles la colaboración con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta en el momento de querer relacionar dos tablas en una tabla tengo una tabla con nombre discos, con un campo con nombre Iddisco (Que es llave primaria) y que es de tipo entero int(11), tengo otra tabla con nombre canciones que tiene un campo foraneo llamado iddisco que igualmente es de tipo int(11) y que tiene registros, esta tabla la tuve que importar desde Access pues se me había dañado por cuestiones de registros.

El hecho es que necesito relacionar las dos tablas, pero al momento de relacionarlas en la herramienta Diseñador del phpmyadmin no me permite realizar el proceso correspondiente, pese a que me dice el phpmyadmin de que me muestra la herramienta “Crear relación”.

Comment: no te permite.. porque tira un error.. que error? y estas seguro que todas las claves de la tabla que importaste estan en la otra tabla?

Comment: Si, eso se podría pasar porque puede existir una cancion que tenga un Iddisco que no exista. O que quizas alguno de los dos tipos de dato entre la relacion sean distintos, por ejemplo que alguno de los dos sea unisgned y el otro no.

Comment: *pero al momento de relacionarlas en la herramienta Diseñador del phpmyadmin no me permite realizar el proceso correspondiente* Comprendo que las interfaces gráficas en muchos casos facilitan el trabajo, pero para casos como este (migración de otra BD), para normalización, etc... es mejor que te fajes con el código SQL en sí mismo. Así, desde la consola, puedes ejecutar los `create table` e ir corrigiendo en los datos los posibles errores de inconsistencia. Trabajar con la interfaz gráfica sobre datos con error en vez de agilizar, retrasa el trabajo.

Comment: Otro problema de las interfaces gráficas es que pueden impedirte que aprendas el lenguaje (SQL en este caso) y que al final el tiempo que crees ganar con la interfaz gráfica lo pierdes centuplicado, al no poder resolver con rapidez siquiera problemas sencillos al no conocer el lenguaje. Y, algo más grave: podrías estar creando modelos de datos disfuncionales, por lo mismo, por no conocer el lenguaje. Las interfaces gráficas, en muchos casos, son un verdadero lastre si sólo te ciñes a ellas y no vas más allá. Otra cosa muy distinta es usarlas cuando ya sabes lo que hay detrás.

Comment: Cordial saludo, muchas gracias comento de que quite los registros de las tablas de la bases de datos mencionadas, pero  desafortunadamente al querer relacionarlas en el diseñador el phpmyadmin, no me deja relacionar todavía las tablas, no entiendo por que persiste ese error debido a que como ya dije,  las tablas ya no tienen registros .

Comment: Muestra el contenido de los `CREATE TABLE` y el mensaje de error que obtienes. Sin eso nosotros no podemos adivinar lo que pasa.